# What is illegal about using curl with this URL?

Tags: curl, amazon-advertising-api

I have the below URL:

```
https://amazon-advertising-api-reports-prod-euamazon.s3.amazonaws.com/apj6jra9ng5v4-avp9363n2w589-report-campaign-45f7c968-d7e8-4d8e-a6ef-2b144268ab36.json.gz?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210930T164837Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-Credential=AKIXXXXXXXXXZ6X%2F20210930%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=2a549XXXXXXXXXX0e61f43166c267eaafedf8
```

It's an original response from Amazon's advertising API with just a few elements replaced by 'X' where there are normal characters you wolud expect in a signature or Credential.

If I copy and paste this url into my browser I can download the file as I would expect. When trying to retrieve this file using any variation of the following `curl` commands ...

```
curl -o $REPORT_DATA_FILE_GZ "$REPORT_DOWNLOAD_URL\"

or 

curl -o $REPORT_DATA_FILE_GZ "\"$REPORT_DOWNLOAD_URL\""

or 

curl -o $REPORT_DATA_FILE_GZ $REPORT_DOWNLOAD_URL
```

... I am getting the error `URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`. But I'm certain I am passing the `REPORT_DOWNLOAD_URL` and `REPORT_DATA_FILE_GZ` variables with correct values.

I display them with `echo` just before the call to `curl` to ensure they are valid.

I also cannot see any characters that look invalid to me in the URL.

All requests to curl are made before my test calls in the browser, so the short expiry period provided by the amazon-advertising-api (30 seconds) would not have expired by that time.

As per the comment I'm running this under Ubuntu 20.04, on WSL2, but most other curl request are working fine.

Comment: What environment are you running this in?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ubuntu 20.04 running on WSL / Windows 11

Comment: `echo` may not show you everything that's in a variable, espeically on a terminal i.e. interactively. Try `printf '%q\n' "$REPORT_DOWNLOAD_URL"`.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 there was a rogue `\r` at the end variable. That's solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution based on the output suggested by @dave_thompson_085. I extracted the `$REPORT_DOWNLOAD_URL` from the header of a different response and it still contained the `\r` at the end.